# How to properly configure PHPMailer - currently getting errors when sending emails

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, phpmailer

I'm having trouble getting my script that sends invoices to customers to work reliably. For a while, the script was working totally fine, and we weren't getting any errors. However, recently, one of our customers notified us that they received error output after they placed their order, and I've narrowed it down to the part of the script that sends out the email with the invoice attached.

The error that we get is:

```
Warning:stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL 
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in 
path/to/phpmailer/phpmailer/class.smtp.php on line 355
```

At that time the PHPMailer configuration I was using was:

```php
// enable SMTP debugging.
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Set SMTP host name.
$mail->Host = "smtp.netregistry.net";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
// Username and Password;
$mail->Username = $email;
$mail->Password = $email_pw;
$mail->Port = 25;
// Message information bellow
```

Based on some research, I found that port 25 is often blocked to try prevent spam and it also used by ISPs (correct?). So I re-read NetRegistry's mail server documentation, as well as talked to their support. If I wanted to use SSL, I needed to use port 465, otherwise I should use port 587.

So, on my local windows machine using XAMPP, I tried using the following configuration:

```php
// Server Settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.netregistry.net";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $email;
$mail->Password = $email_pw;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
```

And this was all put inside a try catch block, where I was catching an Exception based on what I read about how PHPMailer handles errors and warnings.

This worked totally fine on my local machine, and I was able to reliably and regularly send emails with these settings. However, when I uploaded this to the remote host, it did not send any of the emails (it's been 4 days since I tried this), and did not produce any error output despite the catch block echoing a string that states that an error has occurred. I've run the different configurations with the SMTPDebug argument set to 2, and that gave me the following.

When running the script on the remote host with my original settings (port 25) when it fails:

```
2019-03-25 21:10:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.netregistry.net
2019-03-25 21:10:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO website.com.au
2019-03-25 21:10:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp-1.servers.netregistry.net Hello apache.netregistry.net [202.124.241.203]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250 HELP
2019-03-25 21:10:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2019-03-25 21:10:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in <b>\path\to\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\class.smtp.php</b> on line <b>355</b><br />
2019-03-25 21:10:13 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2019-03-25 21:10:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2019-03-25 21:10:13 SERVER -> CLIENT: �������A�;�   MNb���ʋ�]+�
                                      ���M�m3����Kz����f,�b�����<��t�٢��i�ޜ�w�k��PC����c�g�?���I��"r
                                      ��1���$����kKA�L�G����� ��z�<tC�� �s� BP����Tu�xڼH5����ɧ`���e��ڍF������i[�ql@����Gh�D=[���gh������pV����}������������P
2019-03-25 21:10:13 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: �������A�;�    MNb���ʋ�]+�
                                      ���M�m3����Kz����f,�b�����<��t�٢��i�ޜ�w�k��PC����c�g�?���I��"r
                                      ��1���$����kKA�L�G����� ��z�<tC�� �s� BP����Tu�xڼH5����ɧ`���e��ڍF������i[�ql@����Gh�D=[���gh������pV����}������������P
2019-03-25 21:10:13 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
<strong> There was an error sending your packing slip</strong>
```

When I run the script with my updated settings (SSL on port 465):

```
2019-03-25 22:15:21 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
2019-03-25 22:15:21 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
<strong> There was an error sending your packing slip</strong>
```

I'm guessing a key problem is I'm not understanding something correctly here, so if someone could help me to understand where I'm going wrong, that would be great.

Thanks.

EDIT:
One thing I did forget to mention that when talking to Net Registry support today, they suggested setting the Host to `localhost` and the port to 25. This didn't work.

Comment: I currently have a similar issue. $mail->Host='localhost'; works for me as long as I set my Netregistry CPanel's PHP version to 5.5 or less. Unfortunately I need a higher version for a 3rd party library I'm using. Hope this helps you troubleshoot.

Comment: To clarify my above comment, using localhost and port 465 (not 25 as NR suggested to you) without changing SSL setting works for me on PHP 5.5 or less on NR Cpanel hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time learning about how the handshake works, that because the mail server would sometimes offer TLS, PHPMailer will automatically accept and begin to use TLS.

I'm guessing this leads to a problem with verifying netregistry's ssl certificates somehow.

You can stop PHPMailer from automatically using TLS with the SMTPAutoTLS flag. I did have to keep using port 25 however. So my config settings became:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.netregistry.net";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "email";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
```

I think maybe PHPMailer should probably improve their documentation on this because it wasn't particularly obvious, but under the encryption section of the [troubleshooting wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) the docs mention it. Radcore's edit to his answer also included this flag, however I didn't notice it, and it wasn't called out explicitly, so I'm creating a separate answer to highlight it specifically.

Another resource I found helpful when trying to understand what was happening was [Amazon's guide to debugging SMTP Conversations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/debugging-smtp-conversations-part-1-how-to-speak-smtp/). It gave me a better understanding of what all the debug output meant.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is a good reference for Netregistry PHPmailer woes.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the exact same problem with Netregistry. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere but here's what works for us.

The settings required seem to be currently dependent on the PHP version that has been set in your NetRegistry CPanel.

Using localhost as host works for version PHP 5.5 or less.

For native version or above (>= PHP 5.6) we have to set host to the cpanel address for example:

$mail->Host = "cpxxx.ezyreg.com";

here's our full working settings for PHP 5.6 (default for netregistry As far as I can tell)

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = "cpxxx.ezyreg.com"; //for PHP 5.5 or less on NR this must be "localhost"
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
```

**Edit**:
I had the same issue on another NR CPanel site on PHP 5.6 and the only way I found to work around it was to use an unsecure SMTP connection and localhost. Here are the working settings for that site.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

//username and password below probably unused
//but this is a straight copy paste from our working site.
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $pass;

$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 
$mail->IsSMTP();
```

Comment: The current version we have for our cloud server is 5.6. I believe I have tried using localhost already, but I can try again when I get a chance.